# Do Morse functions induce embeddings?

Tags: morse-theory, embeddings

Does the existence of Morse functions on smooth manifolds imply Whitney's embedding theorem?

(That is, given a smooth manifold $M$, does the existence of a Morse function $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ imply that there is an embedding $M \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ without using Whitney's embedding theorem?)

Comment: No, there's little relation between Morse functions and embeddings.  Given an embedding in euclidean space you can make the projections to the coordinate axis Morse functions. . . and similarly given an embedding in a suitably high-dimensional space you can ensure any morse function can be realized as a coordinate function.  Those are the only close relations that come to mind.

Answer (score 4):

Take 4 Morse functions on $\mathbb{RP}^2$, chosen generically so that they embed the real projective plane into $\mathbb{R}^4$. Pull these functions back to the 2-sphere, where they are still Morse functions. Then you have lots of Morse functions, but they don't embed the sphere into anything, only immersing the sphere. Use the same argument with any finite number of Morse functions on any compact manifold with nontrivial fundamental group, by pulling back to any finite covering space. The Morse property of Morse functions is too local to give global embeddings.